# Scala for-loop. Getting index in consice way

Tags: scala, loops, yield

In this code I want to increment `index` to put it to each `yield`ing result.

```
var index=0

for(str <- splitToStrings(text) ) yield  {

  if (index != 0) index += 1               // but index is equal to `0` all the time

  new Word(str, UNKNOWN_FORM, index )
}
```

Why I can not change `index` ? And what the best way to implement this logic then, trying to be concise?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `zipWithIndex` method on most sequence-like collections will give you a zero-based index, incrementing with each element:

```
for ((str, index) <- splitToStrings(text).zipWithIndex)
  yield new Word(str, UNKNOWN_FORM, index)
```

Comment: That's nice. I've already seen this kind of transformation. But it still in passive knowledge. That's concise indeed.

Comment: wouldn't that be inefficient?

Answer (score 6):

Because initially index is set to 0, thus your condition `index != 0` is never executes to true and index is never got incremented. <s>Maybe you don't need this condition? Maybe you can count results afterwards?</s> Now I see that index is used within loop. Then you have to either use [@BenJames answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16883955/298389) or go recursive.

Comment: yep. that was stupid fro my side. at least I'm glad that no surprise from yield. (I just put it because I want to start from 0-index). I tent to think that something goes not right way because of scala but not me :). but this differennt case %) there are many surprises I've got recently.. that's why

Answer (score 3):

`zipWithIndex` will copy and create a new collection, so better make it lazy when the collection is potentially large

```
for ((str, index) <- splitToStrings(text).view.zipWithIndex)
  yield new Word(str, UNKNOWN_FORM, index)
```

In fact, if you are working with an indexed sequence, then a more efficient way is to use `indices`, which produces the range of all indices of this sequence.

```
val strs = splitToStrings(text)

for(i <- strs.indices) yield  {
  new Word(strs(i), UNKNOWN_FORM, i )
}
```

Comment: this will go go though whole list all the time to get the item by index: strs(i). might be slow.

Comment: updated answer. Sequence need to be indexed in order to provide a good random access performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
splitToStrings(text).foldLeft(0,List[Word]){(a,b) => {
   if(a._1!=0) (a._1+1,new Word(str, UNKNOWN_FORM, index) :: b)
   else (a._1,new Word(str, UNKNOWN_FORM, index) :: b)
}}
```

I am using `foldLeft` here with a tuple as: starting base with `index = 0` and an empty `List`. I then iterate over each element.

Above `a` is this tuple. I check the `index` value and increment it. Else I dont add the `index`. And I add the new `Word` to the list.

Ultimately in the end you get a tuple containing the index value and the total List containing all Words.

Comment: Code like this could easily use some explanatory words to go with it.